# Technical terms correctly interpreted

Tags: java

This is basically not a coding question but a technical correction if you will. I can't ask this in a English language forum cause they would not understand all the technical jargon.

So this is the code I have.

```
1. public class ExamQ1a
2. {
3. public static void main(String[] args)
4. {
5. int x = 27;
6. int y = 5;
7. double z = x / y
8. System.out.println(x = x, y = y, z = z);
9. }
10. }
```

This is the question that I am asked

> (i) When the program is compiled in BlueJ, the following error message
>   is shown: ';' expected and the statement on line 7 is highlighted.
>   Explain what the problem is and how to fix it.

This is the answer that I gave

> i)The problem is there is no indication for the end of the statement,
>   thus the compiler will not  treat the statement  double z = x /y as a
>   the end of the statement and then assumes the following sentence is
>   the continuation of the statement. Which in fact is not.  The fix to
>   this error will be  double z = x/y;

So would like to know if I have used the technical terms correctly, tks

Comment: I believe the writer of the test is looking for the term "compile time error" as well.

Comment: technical terms correct but I think still you can explain it further details

Comment: Your answer is correct but if this question is part of your test/homework you can wait till the results are out and check for yourself. This is no place to get things reviewed.If you have any information worth sharing(something you found out technically, something that can be researched further or if you need help regarding some code that you tried but couldnot fix it) post only then.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is reasonable, and certainly not factually incorrect.  There is a minor technical error, in that Java does not have "sentences".

However, in an ideal answer you probably include a more precise reasoning of why the compiler has diagnosed this as a syntax error, and specifically a missing semicolon.

The parser sees the following sequence of symbols:

```
double z = x / y System . out . println
```

It parses the first two symbols as a declarator, and the '=' as the start of an initializer.  Then it tries to parse an expression.  Everything goes fine until it see 'y' followed by 'System'.  Basically you cannot have two identifiers in a row in the middle of an expression.  The symbols that would be legal at this point are the infix operator symbols, a '(', a '[' or a '.'.  Anything else is a syntax error.

The compiler writers have made the call that if the compiler sees an unexpected identifier symbol at this point in the parse, the *most likely* explanation is that the programmer has left off the semicolon at the end of the statement.  And this case, the diagnosis is correct - the problem IS a missing semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine to me except I would use the words `following line` instead of `following sentence`